# why i am getting "command failed with exit code ENOENT" when adding ios in cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova

I am creating one cross platform app in cordova i am getting below error:

```
Creating ios project...
Error: C:\Users\Jay\.cordova\lib\ios\cordova\3.4.1\bin\create: Command failed wi
th exit code ENOENT
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cord
ova\src\superspawn.js:126:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:795:12)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't add the ios platform to your cordova project from an OS other than Mac OS X.

It's because cordova needs XCode to be present so it can create an XCode project with which it will build the ios binaries.

[See the official documentation here.](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/ios/index.html)

**Relevant part** :

> Apple® tools required to build iOS applications run only on the OS X operating system on Intel-based Macs. Xcode® 6.0 (the minimum required version) runs only on OS X version 10.9 (Mavericks) or greater, and includes the iOS 8 SDK (Software Development Kit). To submit apps to the Apple App Store℠ requires the latest versions of the Apple tools.